# Can I apply something like a mask to apply proportional editing to only some connected vertices in blender 2.8?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, masking

Can I apply something like a mask to apply proportional editing to only some connected vertices in blender 2.8?  For example I only want to move the verts on the right side of this leg in proportional editing in the following image:
[image: Before Proportional edit]
[image: After proportional edit]
Given this, is it possible to exclude the verts on the left(the front of the model) leg from this edit to prevent distorting the verts I have just positioned?  I though you could apply masks in blender some how, but I can't find anything on masks for proportional edits in 2.8.

Comment: I'd also go for Proportional edit as answered below, but for future reference, not just for this problem, 'cage rigging' can come in handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the vertices/edges/faces you don't want to be affected by proportional editing and hit <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them, when you're done with the proportional edit, unhide with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> .

You have now done a proportional editing that did not affect the hidden vertices/edges/faces.

Comment: I was not aware that hiding/unhiding was this trivial with shortcuts, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Working with Proportional Edit, I think that you could get by here with just scrolling down the circumference of your brush and get it to work. Hiding the verts you don't want to affect could work as well, but that might be to much to do for a simple block out.